# Password Reset email issue

Tags: magento-1.9, password-recovery

I have been sent an email from a customer this morning. The password reset email has a link which doesn't work. The hyperlink to the page is not there. Where do I find this in Magento 1.9 to rectify the issue?

Comment: Is the link not in the email, or does the link lead to a blank page, or does it lead to a 404?

Comment: There is a button on the email which should link to the webpage to reset the password. However, the button hasn't been hyperlinked. Meaning customers are unable to click.

Answer (score 1):

Check your email templates. By default, email templates are under `System > Transactional Emails`. Normally the password reset email shouldn't be there, but check if a module put one there.

Then check `app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html`. That file should look like this:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td class="action-content">
        <h1>{{htmlescape var=$customer.name}},</h1>
        <p>There was recently a request to change the password for your account.</p>
        <p>If you requested this password change, please reset your password here:</p>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="action-button" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}"><span>Reset Password</span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>If you did not make this request, you can ignore this message and your password will remain the same.</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Also check `app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/locale/en_US/` and see if there is a `template/email` folder overriding email templates.

Comment: My issue, password reset mail working but it takes a long time to the sent customer, once customer received its shows, reset password link expired. How can i solve this issue?